# Why does my git repo throw errors when pushing to deployment server?

Tags: php, git, github, push, git-push

I recently set a a repo up on Beanstalk app to deploy my app.

I have a repo and a submodule in it with the following settings.

In .git/config I have:

```
[submodule "vendor/php-instagram-api/php-instagram-api"]
    path = vendor/php-instagram-api/php-instagram-api
    url = git@made-by-mark.beanstalkapp.com:/made-by-mark/everydayfolk.git
```

In my .git/.gitmodules I have:

```
[submodule "phpinstagram"]
    path = vendor/php-instagram-api/php-instagram-api
    url = git@made-by-mark.beanstalkapp.com:/made-by-mark/everydayfolk.git
```

Is there a conflict here? When I commit I get no errors but when I do `git push beanstalk master` in the beanstalk deployment area I get an error saying:

> Warning: Permanently added
>   'made-by-mark.beanstalkapp.com,50.31.156.71' (RSA) to the list of
>   known hosts. fatal: reference is not a tree:
>   fc4d8cf4f05c51e71ddbc7d7b80f639c68b39405 Unable to checkout
>   'fc4d8cf4f05c51e71ddbc7d7b80f639c68b39405' in submodule path
>   'vendor/php-instagram-api/php-instagram-api'

I have tried many fixes but things just aren't getting anywhere. Can anyone see what the issue may be?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a change is made in submodule, but it is not pushed to its repository, but you are trying to push up the superproject.  First push the subproject and then the superproject.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was not adding the php library in vendors using the composer.phar setup in laravel. The submodule was never registered in the header because it was not cloned into the vendor/path folder properly using the correct command.

In short, clone any libraries direct into the vendor folder from github because doing `git submodule add git/url your/vendor/path` will not be recognised it has to be set correctly in the headers in your git repo.

Hope this helps anyone in need of direction.